# How to view the Grid and What is in the Cells Python

Tags: python, list, class

I know this is kinda a long shot since its been a day, but the user inputs a set of coordinates to "place the line" in whatever cell they choose a "*" will be placed in the grid.

My two major problems is getting the grid to show in CarpetSea `__str__` method and getting the line to be placed in the grid as well.

Here is my current code

```
import random
import time

class Coordinate:
    '''
    '''
    def __init__(self, row, col):
        ''' 

        '''
        self.row = row 
        self.col = col

    def __str__(self):
        '''

        '''
        return "(%d, %d)" %(self.row, self.col)

class Cell:
    '''

    '''

    def __init__(self, row, col):
        '''

        '''
        self.coords = Coordinate(row, col)
        self.fish = ""
        self.contains_line = False

    def __str__(self):
        '''
        '''

        if self.fish:
            if self.contains_line:
                result = 'F*'
            else:
                result = 'F'
        else:
            if self.contains_line:
                result = '*'
            else:
                result = ' '

        return result


class CarpetSea:
    '''

    '''

    fish_caught = 0 
    def __init__(self, N):
        '''

        '''

        self.N = N
        self.grid = []
        for i in range(self.N):
            row = []
            for j in range(self.N):
                cell = Cell(i, j)
                row.append(cell)
            self.grid.append(row)


        self.available_fish = ["Salmon", "Marlin", "Tuna", "Halibut"]


    def __str__(self):
        '''
        returns a string representation of a CarpetSea, i.e. display the organized contents of each cell. 
        Rows and columns should be labeled with indices.

        Example (see "Example Run" in the PA8 specs for more):
          0  1  
        --------
        0|M |  |
        --------
        1|  |* |
        --------

        Note: call Cell's __str__() to get a string representation of each Cell in grid
        i.e. "M " for Cell at (0,0) in the example above
        '''        

        return " 0  1  \n -------- \n 0| %s  | %s  | \n -------- \n 1| %s  | %s  | \n -------- "%(self.grid[x,y].fish for x in range(self.N) for y in range(self.N))


    def randomly_place_fish(self):
        '''
        randomly selects coordinates of a cell and randomly selects a fish from the available_fish list attribute. 
        Marks the cell as containing the fish.
        '''

        cell = random.choice(random.choice(self.grid))
        cell.fish = random.choice(self.available_fish)
        fish_name = cell.fish[0]
        return(fish_name)


    def drop_fishing_line(self, line_coords):
        '''
        accepts the location of the user's fishing line (a Coordinate object). 
        Marks the cell as containing the line.
        '''        

        #somehow I'm supposed to get something like this
        line_cell = self.grid[users_coords.row][users_coords.col]


        self.contains_line = True


    def check_fish_caught(self):
        '''
        If the cell containing the fishing line also contains a fish, returns the fish. 
        Otherwise, return False.

        '''

        if str(self.grid) == "F*":
            print("The fish was caught!")

        else:
            print("The fish was not caught!")

    def display(self):
        '''
        to see the grid and check to see if everything is working


        # header
        #for i in range(len(self.grid[0])): # to get numbers of columns
            #print('{:3d}'.format(i), end='') #prints the top 0 and 1
        print("  0   1")
        # grid
        print('-'*8)
        for i, row in enumerate(self.grid):

            print('0|'.format(i), end='') #prints the 0 and 1 on the lefrt

            for cell in row: 
                print('{:2s}|'.format(str(cell)), end="")

            print()
            print('-'*8)

        #return "0    1 \n -------- \n" for i, row in enumerate(self.grid)       
            '''
class GameStats:
    hour = 0
    fish = CarpetSea.fish_caught
    fish = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.time = time

    def __str__(self):
        average = CarpetSea.fish_caught / GameStats.hour
        return "Total amount of hours played: %d \nTotal amound of fish caught: %d\n On aveage you caught %.2f fish her hour"%(self.hour, CarpetSea.fish_caught, average)        

    def total_time_passed(self):
        '''
        calcuate the total time played in the game 
        '''
        print("One hour has passed...")
        self.time = time.sleep(1)
        GameStats.hour += 1

    def Total_num_of_fish():
        '''
        seeing the total number of fish caught
        '''
        if str(CarpetSea.grid) == "F*":
            GameStats.fish += 1 

    def Average_amount_of_fish(self):
        '''
        average amount of fish caught in the time played
        '''
        self.average_fish = self.fish / self.hour


def main():

    '''

    '''
    print("Welcome to Dilbert's Carpet Fishing Game!")
    print("To play, you will cast your fishing line into a location in Carpet Sea")
    print("After a certain amount of time, you will reel in your line adn find out if you caught a fish!")
    print("You can keep re-casting and re-reeling until you want to quit")

    print("\n")

    #user_row = str(input("Please enter a row: "))
    #user_col = str(input("Please enter a column: "))
    user_row = 2
    user_col = 2
    line_coords = Coordinate(user_row, user_col)

    while True:

        print(line_coords)
        Coordinate(2,2)
        info = CarpetSea(2)
        game = GameStats()

        info.randomly_place_fish()
        info.drop_fishing_line(line_coords)
        #print(info)
        game.total_time_passed()
        info.check_fish_caught()

        info.display()

        answer = str(input("Please enter 'y' to continue or 'n' to end: "))

        if answer == "n":
            break


    gameinfo = GameStats()
    print(gameinfo)


main()
```

Comment: do you mean `info.grid[0][0].fish` and `info.grid[0][0].contains_line` (use other values instead of `0`)

Comment: the placement of the fish is random and the user determines where the line will go. So I'm not really sure what you mean @furas

Comment: you asked how to see what is in grid - you have to get values from every cell and print it `for y in range(2): for x in range(2): print( info.grid[y][x].fish ) ; print( info.grid[y][x].contains_line )`. Or I don't understand your problem.

Comment: in `__str__` you have to use `if/elif/else` to return correct value.

Comment: For your code to see the grid, do I put it in the main function?

Comment: if you put in `main()` then you have to use `info.grid...`, if you put this somewhere in `CarpetSea` then use `self.grid...`

Comment: I tried doing the if statements for the __str__ funtion for cell, but I get the error     

if self.fish in self.coords:
TypeError: argument of type 'Coordinate' is not iterable

How can I make this work?

@furas

Comment: you have to check `if self.fish == ''`

Comment: Why do I want to check to see if self.fish == " " ? Is it testing weither or not the fish is in the cell? do I need to do the same thing with contains line?

Comment: not `' '` (one space) but `''` (empty string) - if `self.fish` is empty string then there is no fish.

Comment: BTW: `input()` always returns string and you don't need `str()`

Comment: BTW: don't change code in question (better add new belowe) because when others will read question and see new code they will not know what is your problem (and someones will downvote or vote for closing/deleting question)

Comment: in `check_fish_caught` you have to use `if str(self.grid[row][column]) == "F*":`

Comment: How do I take the users inputed coordante (a string) and make it into a coordinate for the drawing? And is there a way to get the entire picture into __str__ because that is the end goal.. @furas Also it says row and column are undefined

Comment: I have added my current code, but I am still running into some problems, that I have now written in my questioon @furas

Comment: I have run into some problems with the home stretch of the project, but I have changed my question to make it easier to read, and yesterdays problems are solved @furas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display grid you can do in `main()`

```
for y in range(2): 
    for x in range(2): 
       print( info.grid[y][x].fish )
       print( info.grid[y][x].contains_line )
```

or if you create correct `__str__` in Cell

```
for y in range(2): 
    for x in range(2): 
       print( info.grid[y][x] )
```

or saver - without `range()`

```
for row in info.grid: 
    for cell in row: 
       print( cell )
```

You can also create function in `CarpetSea` - then you use `self` instead of `info`

```
def display(self):

    for row in self.grid: 
        for cell in row: 
           print( cell )
```

---

`__str__` in `Cell` needs `if/elif/else` to correctly display values

```
def __str__(self):
    '''
    '''

    if self.fish: # the same as: if self.fish == ''
        if self.contains_line: # the same as: if self.contains_line == True"
            result = 'F*'
        else:
            result = 'F'
    else:
        if self.contains_line:
            result = '*'
        else:
            result = ' '

    return result
```

---

**EDIT:** for now code looks like this (but it still needs work)

```
import random

class Coordinate:
    '''
    '''
    def __init__(self, row, col):
        ''' 

        '''
        self.row = row 
        self.col = col

    def __str__(self):
        '''

        '''
        return "(%d, %d)" %(self.row, self.col)

class Cell:
    '''

    '''

    def __init__(self, row, col):
        '''

        '''
        self.coords = Coordinate(row, col)
        self.fish = ""
        self.contains_line = False

    def __str__(self):
        '''
        '''

        if self.fish:
            if self.contains_line:
                result = 'F*'
            else:
                result = 'F'
        else:
            if self.contains_line:
                result = '*'
            else:
                result = ' '

        return result


class CarpetSea:
    '''

    '''
    num_of_fish = 0 
    total_time = 0 

    def __init__(self, N):
        '''

        '''
        self.N = N
        self.grid = []
        for i in range(self.N):
            row = []
            for j in range(self.N):
                cell = Cell(i, j)
                row.append(cell)
            self.grid.append(row)


        self.available_fish = ["Salmon", "Marlin", "Tuna", "Halibut"]


    def __str__(self):
        '''
        returns a string representation of a CarpetSea, i.e. display the organized contents of each cell. 
        Rows and columns should be labeled with indices.

        Example (see "Example Run" in the PA8 specs for more):
          0  1  
        --------
        0|M |  |
        --------
        1|  |* |
        --------

        Note: call Cell's __str__() to get a string representation of each Cell in grid
        i.e. "M " for Cell at (0,0) in the example above
        '''
        return " 0  1  \n -------- \n 0| %s  | %s  | \n -------- \n 1| %s  | %s  | \n -------- "%(self.grid[x,y].fish for x in range(self.N) for y in range(self.N))


    def randomly_place_fish(self):
        '''
        randomly selects coordinates of a cell and randomly selects a fish from the available_fish list attribute. 
        Marks the cell as containing the fish.
        '''

        cell = random.choice(random.choice(self.grid))
        cell.fish = random.choice(self.available_fish)

    def drop_fishing_line(self, users_coords):
        '''
        accepts the location of the user's fishing line (a Coordinate object). 
        Marks the cell as containing the line.
        '''

        #this sould put the two numbers in a list
        users_coords = users_coords.split(" ")

        x = users_coords[0]
        y = users_coords[1]

        x,y = [], []
        for l in self.grid:
            x.append(self.grid[0])
            y.append(self.grid[1])

    def check_fish_caught(self):
        '''
        If the cell containing the fishing line also contains a fish, returns the fish. 
        Otherwise, return False.


        if Cell.fish in #appended value of users_coords
            return True
        else:
            return False
         pass

        '''

    def display(self):
        '''
        to see the grid and check to see if everything is working
        '''

        # header

        for idx in range(len(self.grid[0])): # to get numbers of columns
            print('{:3d}'.format(idx), end='')
        print()

        # grid

        print('-'*8)

        for idx, row in enumerate(self.grid):

            print('{}|'.format(idx), end='')

            for cell in row: 
                print('{:2s}|'.format(str(cell)), end="")

            print()
            print('-'*8)

class GameStats:
    def __init__(self, ):
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        pass        


def main():

    '''

    '''
    #user_coords = input("Please enter the coordnate that you wihsh to place your line: ")
    users_coords = ("0 0")

    print(users_coords)

    Coordinate(2,2)
    info = CarpetSea(2)
    info.randomly_place_fish()
    info.randomly_place_fish()
    info.randomly_place_fish()
    info.drop_fishing_line(users_coords)
    info.check_fish_caught()

    info.display()

main()
```

Comment: When I run all of this code, I am printed with False four times and the memory location for what I think the grid is

Comment: You changed your code and I did't test it yet - I still use your original code.

Comment: Do you want me to keep my code the same? Or update it with the changes I make?

Comment: it correct that it print `False` because you print values in `info.grid[y][x].fish` and `print( info.grid[y][x].contains_line` which have empty string and `False`. You doesn't use `Cell.__str__` yet.

Comment: in question keep oryginal code and belowe add new code with all modifications (which you can update later)

Comment: Okay! So how do I get the fish and string to go into the cells? I have some code, but I dont think it is changing the grid

Comment: see new full code in answer - it add 3 random fishes.

Comment: Which code added the fish to the grid? and can I put your display grid as the __str__ function? will it still work the same?

Comment: `randomly_place_fish` adds `fish`. I modify `display`. To use `display` as `__str__` you have to concatenate all in one string (ie. `result`) and use `return result` - you can't use `print()`

Comment: How can I make it one fish instead of three? And how do I add the line as well?

Comment: I use `randomly_place_fish()` three times - keep only one `randomly_place_fish()` to have only one fish.

Comment: My teachers instructions say to have the picture stored in __str__ is there a way to get the picture in the __str__ function, or at least the final drawing the the line as well? This way I can check if the user caught the fish